# how to use not in condition in case statement in where clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to use not in condition with the case for conditional join in SQL but I am getting an error.

```
select * FROM #tmpInterfaceUpdateTriger tmpTrg 

INNER JOIN Interface.InterfaceTrigger trg (NOLOCK) ON   
       tmpTrg.InterfaceTriggerID = trg.InterfaceTriggerId
INNER JOIN DataCollection.NonCustodialParentRelationship ncrp                  
     ON trg.InterfaceTriggerCode NOT IN                                      
     case when trg.IndividualId = ncrp.ChildIndividualId
             then ('AddressChange','EmploymentChange','GoodCauseChange','AbsentParentChange','CSSanctions') end
```

Comment: It's generally much better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of a `case` _expression_ in `WHERE` and `ON` clauses.

Comment: It seems you want to join on `trg.IndividualId = ncrp.ChildIndividualId AND trg.InterfaceTriggerCode NOT IN ('AddressChange', 'EmploymentChange', 'GoodCauseChange', 'AbsentParentChange', 'CSSanctions')`. Do you also want to join records where `trg.IndividualId` has no matching `ncrp.ChildIndividualId`? If so, on what criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM #tmpInterfaceUpdateTriger tmpTrg

INNER JOIN Interface.InterfaceTrigger trg (NOLOCK)
  ON tmpTrg.InterfaceTriggerID = trg.InterfaceTriggerId
INNER JOIN DataCollection.NonCustodialParentRelationship ncrp
  ON trg.IndividualId = ncrp.ChildIndividualId
WHERE trg.InterfaceTriggerCode NOT IN ('AddressChange', 'EmploymentChange', 'GoodCauseChange', 'AbsentParentChange', 'CSSanctions')
```

Comment: i cant use above query as based on the individualid i need to change the not in condition as well

Comment: @AnubhootiBhatnagar - then use `OR` for second `not in` condition. You should have given that condition in the question as well.